# C# Custom Attribute, Targets.Method WHERE returntype = type && IsStatic

Tags: c#, attributes

So, I have a custom attribute that looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAttribute: System.Attribute
{
    private string name;
    public double version;

    public MyAttribute(string _name)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        version = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add the following conditions to this attribute:

```
Method.ReturnType = typeof(specificClass) 

Method.IsStatic
```

Also, how do I implement the following condition?

```
public static void Do(Func<type> func) where func : MyAttribute //make sure Func<type> is decorated with my attribute
{
    //do something with 'func'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. [`AttributeUsage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9(v=vs.140).aspx) determines how a custom attribute class can be used.

The first `AttributeUsage` argument ([`ValidOn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6)) must be one or more elements of the [`AttributeTargets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx) enumeration. Multiple target types can be linked together with the OR operator, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
class NewPropertyOrFieldAttribute : Attribute { }
```

If the `AllowMultiple` argument is set to true, then the resulting attribute can be applied more than once to a single entity, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
class MultiUseAttr : Attribute { }

[MultiUseAttr]
[MultiUseAttr]
class Class1 { }

[MultiUseAttr, MultiUseAttr]
class Class2 { }
```

If `Inherited` is set to false, then the attribute is not inherited by classes that are derived from a class that is attributed. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
class Attr1 : Attribute { }

[Attr1]
class BClass { }

// In this case Attr1 is not applied to DClass via inheritance.
class DClass : BClass { }
```

That is all parameters that you can control for attribute usage in compile time. You can validate usage scenarios in the run-time via reflection but it's slow and error-prone way.